# xdebug installation failure

Tags: php, ubuntu-14.04, xdebug

how can I install XDebug on Ubuntu 14.04?
I tried to install it through apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-xdebug
```

but I get this error:

```
php5-xdebug : Depends: phpapi-20121212+lfs
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

what's wrong?

Comment: Do you have php5-common installed?

Comment: Check this duplicate question :http://askubuntu.com/questions/856996/cant-install-xdebug-depends-phpapi-20121212-ubuntu-14-04